# Getting content for each file in a directory in a github repo using api

Tags: github-api

I was searching through the api docs. It appear the same api call is being used for getting details except content when a dir is provided and content when a single file is given.

```
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content--code-samples
```

In the case of Response if content is a file

```
  "type": "file",
  "encoding": "base64",
  "size": 5362,
  "name": "README.md",
  "path": "README.md",
  "content": "encoded content ...",
  "sha": "3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/README.md",
  "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/blobs/3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/README.md",
  "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octokit/octokit.rb/master/README.md",
  "_links": {
    "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/blobs/3d21ec53a331a6f037a91c368710b99387d012c1",
    "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/README.md",
    "html": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/README.md"
  }
}
```

In case of Response if content is a directory

```
  {
    "type": "file",
    "size": 625,
    "name": "octokit.rb",
    "path": "lib/octokit.rb",
    "sha": "fff6fe3a23bf1c8ea0692b4a883af99bee26fd3b",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/lib/octokit.rb",
    "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/blobs/fff6fe3a23bf1c8ea0692b4a883af99bee26fd3b",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/lib/octokit.rb",
    "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octokit/octokit.rb/master/lib/octokit.rb",
    "_links": {
      "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/lib/octokit.rb",
      "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/blobs/fff6fe3a23bf1c8ea0692b4a883af99bee26fd3b",
      "html": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/lib/octokit.rb"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "dir",
    "size": 0,
    "name": "octokit",
    "path": "lib/octokit",
    "sha": "a84d88e7554fc1fa21bcbc4efae3c782a70d2b9d",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/lib/octokit",
    "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/trees/a84d88e7554fc1fa21bcbc4efae3c782a70d2b9d",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/tree/master/lib/octokit",
    "download_url": null,
    "_links": {
      "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/contents/lib/octokit",
      "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/octokit.rb/git/trees/a84d88e7554fc1fa21bcbc4efae3c782a70d2b9d",
      "html": "https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/tree/master/lib/octokit"
    }
  }
]
```

How can I get the content too as an output field for all the files in a directory through a single api call. Is there any way to do so?